# how to get data by range time with timestamp format on mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb

how to sort data based on time timestamp format on mongodb data?

I have data with the format as below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5996562c31f238391609f526"),
    "created_at" : 1502683719,
    "uname" : "username_here",
    "source" : "sourcer"
}
...
...
```

I want to find the data with **"created_at"** filter, I tried with a command like this:

```
db.getCollection('data').find({
    'created_at':{
        '$gte':1502683719, 
        '$lt':1494616578 
    }
)
```

the result, all data that has a value of more than or less than the data entered all out.

the format of **"created_at"** is integer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your collection is `users`:

```
db.users.find().sort({created_at: -1})
```

Check out the documentation for more detailed options https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/